# I am getting these two errors while setting up the maven pom.xml file. Does anyone know the reason?

Tags: selenium, maven

I am getting these two errors while setting up the maven pom.xml file. Does anyone know the reason?
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
CoreException: Could not calculate build plan: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.7 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:jar:3.8.7 was not found in https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 during a previous attempt. This failure was cached in the local repository and resolution is not reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced pom.xml /selenium-for-beginners line 13 Maven Project Build Lifecycle Mapping Problem
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:jar:3.8.7 was not found in https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 during a previous attempt. This failure was cached in the local repository and resolution is not reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced  pom.xml /selenium-for-beginners line 1  Maven Configuration Problem

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fXsBP.png)

Comment: Can you please format your question. It is unreadable. Add code as text not as image

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

There is no version 3.8.7 of the `naven-compiler-plugin` in the [official maven repository](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.maven.plugins/maven-compiler-plugin):

switch to 3.10.1

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.maven.plugins/maven-compiler-plugin -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.10.1</version>
</dependency>
```

BTW: You can simply use

```
<properties>
  <maven.compiler.source>17</maven.compiler.source>
  <maven.compiler.target>17</maven.compiler.target>        
</properties>
```

to set the java version for the compiler

Comment: But in my computer java 17 is installed. Is it okay if I mentioned there 1.8 instead of 17.

Comment: C:\Users\Azahar>mvn -version
Apache Maven 3.8.7 (b89d5959fcde851dcb1c8946a785a163f14e1e29)
Maven home: C:\Program Files\apache-maven-3.8.7
Java version: 17.0.5, vendor: Oracle Corporation, runtime: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-17.0.5
Default locale: en_IN, platform encoding: Cp1252
OS name: "windows 11", version: "10.0", arch: "amd64", family: "windows"

Comment: @AkashSk Sorry copy & paste error on my site